# Type one algorithm in two columns but the numbering should continue

Tags: two-column, algorithms

How to type the algorithm displayed in the below image in latex? I search a solution for these switching line numbers from left to right and back. How can I achieve this with continuously incrementing numbers?

[image: paxos algorithm]

Comment: Hi user121848 and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I searched through the relevant posts but none of them has a answer that matches my requirement :( Thing is numbering should be same on both sides

Comment: If you would already have a solution there would be no need for a question. But you could at least provide some code that shows what you have achieved so far. Then we -- the helpers -- don't need to do *everything* from scratch but *only* need to adopt your provided code.

Comment: I have a solution, but I have to wait until the question is open again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some small adjustments to `\leftskip` back-and-forth works for setting something that seems to display in two columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Paxos}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Statex \textbf{Client (Proposer)}

    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \addtolength{\leftskip}{.5\linewidth}%
    \Statex \textbf{Server (Acceptor)}

    \medskip

    \addtolength{\leftskip}{-.5\linewidth}%
    \Statex \textit{Initialization} \dotfill

    \medskip

    \Statex \eqmakebox[lbox][l]{$c$} \textit{$\triangleleft$ command to execute}
    \Statex \eqmakebox[lbox][l]{$t = 0$} \textit{$\triangleleft$ ticket number to try}

    \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
    \addtolength{\leftskip}{.5\linewidth}%
    \Statex \eqmakebox[rbox][l]{$T_{\text{max}} = 0$} \textit{$\triangleleft$ largest issued ticket}
    \Statex
    \Statex \eqmakebox[rbox][l]{$C = {\perp}$} \textit{$\triangleleft$ stored command}
    \Statex \eqmakebox[rbox][l]{$T_{\text{store}} = 0$} \textit{$\triangleleft$ ticket used to store $C$}

    \medskip

    \addtolength{\leftskip}{-.5\linewidth}%    
    \Statex \textit{Phase 1} \dotfill

    \medskip

    \State $t = t + 1$
    \State Ask all servers for ticket~$t$

    \addtolength{\leftskip}{.5\linewidth}
    \If{$t > T_{\text{max}}$}
      \State $T_{\text{max}} = t$
      \State Answer with $\texttt{ok}(T_{\text{store}}, C)$
    \EndIf

    \medskip

    \addtolength{\leftskip}{-.5\linewidth}
    \Statex \textit{Phase 2} \dotfill

    \medskip

    \If{a majority answers \texttt{ok}}
      \State $\text{Pick}(T_{\text{store}}, C)$ with largest $T_{\text{store}}$
      \If{$T_{\text{store}} > 0$}
        \State $c = C$
      \EndIf
      \State Send $\texttt{propose}(t, c)$ to same majority
    \EndIf

    \addtolength{\leftskip}{.5\linewidth}
    \If{$t = T_{\text{max}}$}
      \State $C = c$
      \State $T_{\text{store}} = t$
      \State Answer \texttt{success}
    \EndIf

    \medskip

    \addtolength{\leftskip}{-.5\linewidth}

    \Statex \textit{Phase 3} \dotfill

    \medskip

    \If{a majority answers \texttt{success}}
      \State Send $\texttt{execute}(c)$ to every server
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my second, much simpler solution.

A bit of history: I first thought that setting the algorithm parts in `\vbox`es would be an easy solution. However, it appeared that I had to do quite some trickery to get `algorithmicx` state out of the boxes. But I got that working. But I was not satisfied with the complexity, so I thought of changing it by manipulating the indentation. Unfortunately, I made a silly mistake so that it didn't work 100% (I thought that `algorithmicx` used `\ALG@tlm` to indent the code. But this is an addiditional indentation after `\leftskip`. It had some weird side effects). As I had no more time, I posted my original code. After coming home I got inspired by @Werner's solution, and that solved it. Basically I just had to replace `\ALG@tlm` with `\leftskip` to get it working. I also changed `\rightskip` in the `\Left` macro so that the left hand column doesn't overflow in the right hand column. And I used @Werner's `\vspace{-\baseline}` trick for the `\LeftRight` macro.

So now here is the solution, which basically works the same as @Werner's but with the macros I used in my first solution. The body of the algorithm is unchanged. Only the macros have changed.

The original solution is at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

%%%% Macros for two column algorithms %%%%

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\halfwidth}
\newlength{\halfwidthplus}


\newcommand{\InitTwoCols}{%
  \setlength{\halfwidth}{0.5\textwidth-1em}% separation left/right = 2em
  \setlength{\halfwidthplus}{\textwidth-\halfwidth}%
}

% \Left{ALG} sets ALG in the left hand column 
% This restricts the width of the column so that it doesn't overflow
% into the right hand column. If you want it to overflow, just leave out
% the \Left{} part.

\newcommand{\Left}[1]{%
    \setlength{\rightskip}{\textwidth-\halfwidth}%
    #1\par
    \setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}%
}

% \Right{ALG} sets ALG in the right hand column 

\newcommand{\Right}[1]{%
  \addtolength{\leftskip}{\halfwidthplus}%
  #1\par
  \addtolength{\leftskip}{-\halfwidthplus}%
}

% \LeftRight sets two parts next to each other. It has n optional
% parameter indicating how many lines the left hand part occupies
% (default 1)

\newcommand{\LeftRight}[3][1]{\Left{#2}\vspace{-#1\baselineskip}\Right{#3}}

% \TwoHeads sets two headers, one above each column

\newcommand{\TwoHeads}[2]{%
  \vskip2pt\LeftRight{\Statex \textbf{#1}}{\Statex \textbf{#2}}\vskip2pt}

% \Phase sets a text followed by dots across the full width

\newcommand{\Phase}[1]{\vskip2pt\Statex \emph{#1} \dotfill\par\vskip2pt}

% Redefine \Comment to use \triangleleft instead of \triangleright.
\algrenewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill$\triangleleft$ #1}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Paxos}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \InitTwoCols
  \TwoHeads{Client (Proposer)}{Server (Acceptor)}
  \Phase{Initialization}
  \LeftRight{\Statex $c$ \Comment{command to execute}}{\Statex $T_{max} = 0$ \Comment{largest issued ticket}}

  \Left{\Statex $t = 0$ \Comment{ticket number to try}}
  \Right{\Statex $C = \bot$ \Comment{stored command}}
  \Right{\Statex $T_{store} = 0$ \Comment{ticket used to store C}}

  \Phase{Phase 1}

  \Left{
    \State $t = t + 1$
    \State Ask all servers for ticket t
  }
  \Right{
    \If {$t > T_{max}$}
    \State $T_{max} = t$
    \State Answer with ok($T_{store}, C$)
    \EndIf
  }

  \Phase{Phase 2}

  \Left{
    \If {a majority answers ok}
        \State Pick ($T_{store},C$) with largest $T_{store}$
        \If {$T_{store} > 0$}
            \State $c = C$
        \EndIf
        \State Send propose($t, c$) to same majority    
    \EndIf
  }
  \Right{
    \If {$t = T_{max}$}
        \State $C = c$
        \State $T_{store} = t$
        \State Answer success
    \EndIf
  }

  \Phase {Phase 3}

  \Left{
    \If {a majority answers success}
        \State Send execute($c$) to every server
    \EndIf
  }
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original solution:**

I have a solution, based on the package `algorithmicx`. The solution is quite tricky, however. The left and right parts are typeset in boxes, slightly less than half the `\textwidth`. But because `algorithmicx` maintains all kinds of information about the state of the algorithm (for example block depth, what kind of block is active, current indentation), now this information is updated inside the box, i.e. a group, so at the end of the group we have to get this info out of the group into the surrounding group. I hope I have covered all info that needed to be kept. This is how it looks:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

%%%% Code for two column algorithms %%%%

% This is done by typesetting the algorithm parts in a \vbox slightly
% less than half the \textwidth. However, this causes a problem:
% algorithmicx changes quite a number of "variables" while typesetting
% the algorithm. And when we leave the \vbox, by TeX's grouping
% mechanism, these are reset to the value they had when we entered the
% \vbox. There is one exception: counters, as these are global in LaTeX.
% So when we exit the \vbox, we have to take these values out of the
% box. We do this by copying them to globals at the end of the box, and
% then with \aftergroup we copy these globals back to the variables.
% I hope the following code covers all required variables.
% It would have beenm much easier if algorithmicx would have treated
% these "variables" as globals, which I think is possible.

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\globalsaveone}[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter \expandafter\global \expandafter\expandafter \expandafter\let
  \expandafter\expandafter \csname Global@#1@#2\endcsname \csname #1@#2\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\globalsave}[1]{%
  \globalsaveone{#1}{0}%
  \globalsaveone{#1}{1}%
  \globalsaveone{#1}{2}%
  \globalsaveone{#1}{3}%
  \globalsaveone{#1}{4}%
}
\newcommand{\globalrestoreone}[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter \expandafter\let \expandafter\expandafter \csname #1@#2\endcsname
      \csname Global@#1@#2\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\globalrestore}[1]{%
  \globalrestoreone{#1}{0}%
  \globalrestoreone{#1}{1}%
  \globalrestoreone{#1}{2}%
  \globalrestoreone{#1}{3}%
  \globalrestoreone{#1}{3}%
}
\newcommand{\substundefined}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\@undefined UNDEF\else
  \ifx#1\relax UNDEF\else#1\fi\fi
}
\newlength\Global@ALG@tlm 

\newcommand{\restorecommand}{%
  \ALG@tlm=\Global@ALG@tlm 
  \let\ALG@thisblock\Global@ALG@thisblock
  \let\ALG@thislifetime\Global@ALG@thislifetime
  \let\ALG@thisentity\Global@ALG@thisentity 
  \let\ALG@text\Global@ALG@text
  \let\ALG@entitiecommand\Global@ALG@entitiecommand
  \let\ALG@makebeginrepeat\Global@ALG@makebeginrepeat
  \globalrestoreone{ALG@b@\ALG@L}{\substundefined\ALG@thisentity @\substundefined\ALG@thisblock}%
  \globalrestore{ALG@currentblock}%
  \globalrestore{ALG@currentlifetime}%
  \globalrestore{ALG@ind}%
}

\newcommand{\restorealgorithminfo}{%
  \global\Global@ALG@tlm=\ALG@tlm 
  \global\let\Global@ALG@thisblock\ALG@thisblock
  \global\let\Global@ALG@thislifetime\ALG@thislifetime 
  \global\let\Global@ALG@thisentity\ALG@thisentity 
  \global\let\Global@ALG@text\ALG@text
  \global\let\Global@ALG@entitiecommand\ALG@entitiecommand
  \globalsaveone{ALG@b@\ALG@L}{\substundefined\ALG@thisentity @\substundefined\ALG@thisblock}%
  \global\let\Global@ALG@makebeginrepeat\ALG@makebeginrepeat
  \globalsave{ALG@currentblock}%
  \globalsave{ALG@currentlifetime}%
  \globalsave{ALG@ind}%
  \aftergroup\restorecommand
}
\makeatother

%%% End of Restore part.

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\halfwidth}
\newlength{\halfwidthplus}
\newlength{\halfwidthmin}
\newcommand{\InitTwoCols}{%
  \setlength{\halfwidth}{0.5\textwidth-1em-\leftmargin}%
  \setlength{\halfwidthplus}{\textwidth-\halfwidth-\leftmargin}%
  \setlength{\halfwidthmin}{\halfwidthplus-\halfwidth}%
}

\newcommand{\HalfBox}[1]{\vbox{%
    \hsize=\halfwidth
    \textwidth=\halfwidth
    \linewidth=\halfwidth
    \columnwidth=\halfwidth
    #1%
    \restorealgorithminfo
  }%
}

% \Left sets the algorithm in the left hand half
% \Right sets the algorithm in the right hand half
% \LeftRight sets two parts next to each other
% \TwoHeads sets two headers, one above each half
% \Phase sets a text followed by dots across the full width

\newcommand{\Left}[1]{\noindent\HalfBox{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\Right}[1]{\noindent\hspace*{\halfwidthplus}\HalfBox{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\LeftRight}[2]{\noindent\HalfBox{#1}\hspace{\halfwidthmin}\HalfBox{#2}\par}

\newcommand{\TwoHeads}[2]{\vskip2pt\Statex \makebox[\halfwidthplus][l]{\textbf{#1}}\textbf{#2}\vskip2pt}
\newcommand{\Phase}[1]{\vskip2pt\Statex{\emph{#1} \dotfill}\par\vskip10pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Paxos}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \InitTwoCols
  \TwoHeads{Client (Proposer)}{Server (Acceptor)}
  \Phase{Initialization}
  \LeftRight{\Statex $c$ \Comment{command to execute}}{\Statex $T_{max} = 0$ \Comment{largest issued ticket}}

  \Left{\Statex $t = 0$ \Comment{ticket number to try}}
  \Right{\Statex $C = \bot$ \Comment{stored command}}
  \Right{\Statex $T_{store} = 0$ \Comment{ticket used to store C}}

  \Phase{Phase 1}

  \Left{
    \State $t = t + 1$
    \State Ask all servers for ticket t
  }
  \Right{
    \If {$t > T_{max}$}
    \State $T_{max} = t$
    \State Answer with ok($T_{store}, C$)
    \EndIf
  }

  \Phase{Phase 2}

  \Left{
    \If {a majority answers ok}
        \State Pick ($T_{store},C$) with largest $T_{store}$
        \If {$T_{store} > 0$}
            \State $c = C$
        \EndIf
        \State Send propose($t, c$) to same majority    
    \EndIf
  }
  \Right{
    \If {$t = T_{max}$}
        \State $C = c$
        \State $T_{store} = t$
        \State Answer success
    \EndIf
  }

  \Phase {Phase 3}

  \Left{
    \If {a majority answers success}
        \State Send execute($c$) to every server
    \EndIf
  }
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

**Esthetic Note**: Things like `$T_{max}$` look slightly better when given as `$T_{\mathit{max}}$`.